# How to set tab as default tab in swing

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

My form contains 7 tabs. I want to get 3rd tab as default tab in my application whenever user enter in my application then user will get window with 3rd tab.

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/346608/GUI/java/Default-tab-setting-Swing

Answer (score 4):

Have a look [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jtabbedpane/get-set-selected-tab-in-jtabbedpane/).

In particular, you want to employ this on your JTabbedPane:

```
yourtabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(yourdesiredindex);
```

This explains how to set the current tab in JTabbedPane. You want to put this code in the most appropriate event-handler.

Comment: Bare links are not considered complete answers here.  Copy/paste the relevant code from that page into your answer.

Comment: I know it's a bit short, but I'd like to see where SO says it's inappropriate. For my own learning. *edit* Oh, you're a mod. Will do.

Comment: See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Understood. Thanks for pointing that out Robert. I am a bit new to SO.